# python: can i import the module namespace within the module itself?

Tags: python, scope, python-module

Since variables names are declared local if there is an assignment to them within a function, and I want to access the module variables from within a function, can I import the module name within the module and then use that to access the module variables ?

Example (file name : server.py):

```
import server

bar = 5

def foo():
   server.bar = 10
```

Comment: You don't want only to access, you want to change them. Then the question naturally comes: why do you want to proceed like that , and not with the use of the ``global`` statement, which is precisely intended to allow to do that ?

Comment: Your use of the word 'variable' is incorrect. There are variables in other languages, the word being taken in the sense of _chunk of memory acting like a box, whose content can change_ , but not in Python. There are no box-variables in Python, _all is object_. The only acceptable use of word 'variable' in Python is to designate the name of an object, the only sense in which I saw it used in the official docs. But there's a specific word for this: 'identifier'. So there's no justification to employ the ambiguous and confusioning word 'variable' in Python context.

Comment: _You don't want only to access, you want to change them_ , said I. But it is a supposition of mine. In fact, the motivation of your code is unknown, since it is incomplete. What do you want to obtain with the instruction `server.bar = 10`` ? The question 'why ?' is secondary to the comprehension of what you want to obtain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `global` statement, as suggested in all of the other answers, don't use module level variables, but a class as a container or else another module just for the globals:

```
# mg.py

bar = 5

# server.py
import mg

def foo():
    mg.bar = 10
```

or

```
class mg:
    bar = 5

def foo():
    mg.bar = 10
```

This way you don't need to put `global` statements everywhere, you can re-use those names, and it's clear which `bar` you're referring to.

**Edit:** Also, it is possible to import a module inside itself, but you can't change variables in the main module that way. So this would work:

```
# selfimport.py
import selfimport

def foo():
    print selfimport.foo

bar = 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print selfimport.bar
    foo()
```

But this wouldn't:

```
# selfimport.py
import selfimport

bar = 3

def foo():
    selfimport.bar = 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print selfimport.bar
    foo()
    print bar # bar is still 3!
```

If you're only using the globals as constants, you wouldn't need the `global` statement anyway. You also need to make sure to wrap code you only want to execute in the main module in an `if` statement as above, or you'll recurse.

Comment: So instead of explicitly indicating usage of global variables you suggest hiding it and relying on implicit mechanisms. I tend to consider that as a harmful advise.

Comment: No, I suggest you __not use global variables__, and you refer to those variables __explicitly__ by using the attribute access notation (rather than __implicitly__ when not assigned to in a scope, as you can do with globals).

Answer (score 1):

You can't import it like that, and you don't need to. Just use the module-global variable directly.

```
def foo():
    global bar
    bar = 10
```

you need to declare it global so it gets set, instead of creating a local variable.

Comment: This is wrong, you can import it like that (not that you should).

Comment: Technically you can, but you can get some really strange results by doing that. So you can't do that and expect it to work 100% reliably.

Comment: I'm not sure what effects you mean, if you do as I suggested and wrap code you only want to use in the main module in `if __name__ == '__main__'`, which you should do anyway?

Comment: @agf That doesn't even work. You will have two `server` module instances. the `foo()` method thinks it's setting its own modules `bar`, but it is not. This self-import method may appear to work, but it does not.

Comment: You're right. I'm so used to only using globals as constants I didn't think of that. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
def foo():
  global bar
  bar = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

no, instead use the global statement:

```
def foo():
    global bar
    bar = 10
```